# Conditionally remove function calls in fold expression

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae, fold-expression

I know that I can use SFINAE to disable generation of templated functions based on a condition, but that doesn't really work in this case. I want to initialize an array at compile-time that should contain values that matches a condition. Something like this:

```
template <std::size_t i, class ... Types, class ... Group>
constexpr auto fetch_match(const std::tuple<Group...>& candidates)
{
    if constexpr (is_match<std::tuple<Group...>, i, Types...>())
    {
        auto& group = std::get<i>(candidates);
        return group.template get<Types...>();
    }
}

template <class ... Types, class ... Group, std::size_t ... indices>
constexpr auto get_matches(const std::tuple<Group...>& candidates, std::index_sequence<indices...>)
{
    constexpr std::array views {
        (fetch_match<indices, Types...>(candidates), ...),
    };
    return views;
}
```

I know the code above is wrong and doesn't compile. If the condition isn't filled, then I want the fold expression to not generate that function call. How would I do that?

---

This question might be an XY-problem, so here's a the problem in more detail.

I have a `Registry` that contains `Group`s of heterogeneous data. I want to be able to query all groups that contains the specified sub list of types. For example, `for (const auto& view : registry.get<char, short, int>())` should yield an array with views of the groups that contain `char`, `short` and `int`. I've created a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) below. The problem with the current code is that I have to first create the array and then copy the views, which I'd like to avoid.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>


template <typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr bool contains = (std::is_same<T, Ts>{} || ...);

template <typename Subset, typename Set>
constexpr bool is_subset_of = false;

template <typename... Ts, typename... Us>
constexpr bool is_subset_of<std::tuple<Ts...>, std::tuple<Us...>> = (contains<Ts, Us...> && ...);

template <typename ... T>
struct View
{
    const char* name_of_group;  // For debugging.
    std::tuple<T...> data;
};

template <typename ... Ts>
struct Group
{
    using type_set = std::tuple<Ts...>;
    static const char* name;   // For debugging.

    std::tuple<Ts...> data;

    explicit Group(Ts... values) : data(values...) {}

    template <typename ... Us>
    [[nodiscard]] View<Us...> get() const noexcept
    {
        return { this->name, std::make_tuple(std::get<Us>(this->data)...) };
    }
};

template <class Groups, std::size_t i, class ... Types>
constexpr bool is_match()
{
    using group_type = std::tuple_element_t<i, Groups>;
    bool match = is_subset_of<std::tuple<Types...>, typename group_type::type_set>;
    return match;
}


template <std::size_t i, class ... Types, class ... Group, class Array>
constexpr void add_matches(const std::tuple<Group...>& candidates, Array& matches, std::size_t& index)
{
    if constexpr (is_match<std::tuple<Group...>, i, Types...>())
    {
        auto& group = std::get<i>(candidates);
        matches[index++] = group.template get<Types...>();
    }
}

template <class ... Types, class ... Group, std::size_t ... indices>
constexpr auto get_matches(const std::tuple<Group...>& candidates, std::index_sequence<indices...>)
{
    constexpr std::size_t size = (is_match<std::tuple<Group...>, indices, Types...>() + ... + 0);
    std::array<View<Types...>, size> views {};
    std::size_t index = 0;
    (add_matches<indices, Types...>(candidates, views, index), ...);
    return views;
}


template <typename ... Group>
class Registry
{
public:
    explicit Registry(Group... groups) : groups(groups...) {}

    template <typename ... T>
    auto get()
    {
        constexpr auto indices = std::index_sequence_for<Group...>{};
        return get_matches<T...>(this->groups, indices);
    }

private:
    std::tuple<Group...> groups;
};


using A = Group<char>;
using B = Group<char, short>;
using C = Group<char, short, int>;
using D = Group<char, short, int, long long>;

// Giving the classes names for debugging purposes.
template<> const char* A::name = "A";
template<> const char* B::name = "B";
template<> const char* C::name = "C";
template<> const char* D::name = "D";


int main()
{
    auto registry = Registry(A{0}, B{1,1}, C{2,2,2}, D{3,3,3,3});

    // Should yield an array of size 2 with View<char, short, int>,
    // one from group C and one from Group D.
    for (const auto& view : registry.get<char, short, int>())
    {
        std::cout << "View of group: " << view.name_of_group     << std::endl;
        std::cout << "char: "  << int(std::get<char>(view.data)) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "short: " << std::get<short>(view.data)     << std::endl;
        std::cout << "int: "   << std::get<int>(view.data)       << std::endl;
    }
}
```

---

Trying the suggestion in the comments, the following code is as far as I got.

```
template <class Groups, std::size_t i, class ... Types>
constexpr bool is_match()
{
    using group_type = std::tuple_element_t<i, Groups>;
    bool match = is_subset_of<std::tuple<Types...>, typename group_type::type_set>;
    return match;
}
template <class ... Types, class ... Group, std::size_t ... indices>
constexpr auto build_view_array(const std::tuple<Group...>& candidates, std::index_sequence<indices...>)
{
    std::array views {
            std::get<indices>(candidates).template get<Types...>()...
    };
    return views;
}
template <std::size_t i, class Groups, class TypeSet, std::size_t ... x>
constexpr auto get_matching_indices()
{
    if constexpr (is_match<Groups, i, TypeSet>())
        return std::index_sequence<x..., i>{};
    else
        return std::index_sequence<x...>{};
}
template <std::size_t i, std::size_t j, std::size_t ... rest, class Groups, class TypeSet, std::size_t ... x>
constexpr auto get_matching_indices()
{
    if constexpr (is_match<Groups, i, TypeSet>())
        return get_matching_indices<j, rest..., Groups, TypeSet, i, x...>();
    else
        return get_matching_indices<j, rest..., Groups, TypeSet, x...>();
}

template <class ... Types, class ... Group, std::size_t ... indices>
constexpr auto get_matches(const std::tuple<Group...>& candidates, std::index_sequence<indices...>)
{
    constexpr auto matching_indices = get_matching_indices<indices..., std::tuple<Group...>, std::tuple<Types...>>();
    constexpr auto views = build_view_array<Types...>(candidates, matching_indices);
    return views;
}
```

It feels like it should work, but it won't compile due to the following error:

```
/Users/tedkleinbergman/Programming/ECS/temp.cpp:76:39: error: no matching function for call to 'get_matching_indices'
    constexpr auto matching_indices = get_matching_indices<indices..., std::tuple<Group...>, std::tuple<Types...>>();
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/tedkleinbergman/Programming/ECS/temp.cpp:92:16: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'get_matches<char, short, int, Group<char>, Group<char, short>, Group<char, short, int>, Group<char, short, int, long long> , 0, 1, 2, 3>' requested here
        return get_matches<T...>(this->groups, indices);
               ^
/Users/tedkleinbergman/Programming/ECS/temp.cpp:118:38: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Registry<Group<char>, Group<char, short>, Group<char, short, int>, Group<char, short, int, long long> >::get<char, short, int>' requested here
    for (const auto& view : registry.get<char, short, int>())
                                     ^
/Users/tedkleinbergman/Programming/ECS/temp.cpp:57:16: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'Groups'
constexpr auto get_matching_indices()
               ^
/Users/tedkleinbergman/Programming/ECS/temp.cpp:65:16: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'rest'
constexpr auto get_matching_indices()
               ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: To do this at compile time, you need to operate entirely on index sequences. Build an index sequence that consists of the indices you want to retain. Once you have that index sequence, you can use a fold expression to build the views.

Comment: @raymond you could also do it with constexpr code.  Build a tuple of std integral constant.  I can't figure out how to do it as a constexpr array of indexes, but that might also be possible (pass them as an auto template parameter or something?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, start with an `index_sequence` filter:

```
template<std::size_t I>
using index_t = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;
template<std::size_t I>
constexpr index_t<I> index = {};

template<std::size_t...Is, std::size_t...Js>
constexpr std::index_sequence<Is...,Js...> concatenate( std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::index_sequence<Js...> ) {
  return {};
}
template <class Test>
constexpr auto filter_sequence(std::index_sequence<> sequence, Test test) {
  return sequence;
}

template<std::size_t I0, std::size_t...Is, class Test>
constexpr auto filter_sequence( std::index_sequence<I0, Is...>, Test test )
{
  constexpr auto tail = filter_sequence( std::index_sequence<Is...>{}, test );
  if constexpr ( test(index<I0>) ) {
    return concatenate( std::index_sequence<I0>{}, tail );
  } else {
    return tail;
  }
}
```

we then use these primitives.

```
template <class Group, class ... Types>
constexpr auto get_match_indexes()
{
  constexpr auto test = [](auto I){ return is_match<Group, I, Types...>(); };
  constexpr auto indexes = std::make_index_sequence< std::tuple_size_v<Group> >{};
  constexpr auto retval = filter_sequence( indexes, test );
  return retval;
}
template<class ... Types, class Group, std::size_t...Is>
std::array<sizeof...Is, View<Types...>> get_matches(const Group& candidates, std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
  return {{
    std::get<Is>(candidates).template get<Types...>(), ...
  }};
}
template<class ... Types, class Group>
std::array<sizeof...Is, View<Types...>> get_matches(const Group& candidates ) {
  return get_matches<Types...>( candidates, get_match_indexes<Group, Types...>() );
}
```

or something like that.

Note that some compilers may need to replace `is_match<Group, I, Types...>()` with `is_match<Group, decltype(I)::value, Types...>()`.

There may be typos.  This uses [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) at the least.

`filter_sequence` uses O(n^2) template symbol length and O(n) recursive template instantiation depth.  It can be improved to O(n lg n) length and O(lg n) depth with a tricky code; basically, you need to split `Is...` into `As...` and `Bs...` down the middle and recurse that way.

Here is a log-depth split of an index sequence:

```
template<class A, class B>
struct two_things {
  A a;
  B b;
};
template<class A, class B>
two_things(A,B)->two_things<A,B>;
    
template<class Seq>
constexpr auto split_sequence( index_t<0>, Seq seq ) {
  return two_things{ std::index_sequence<>{}, seq };
}

template<std::size_t I0, std::size_t...Is>
constexpr auto split_sequence( index_t<1>, std::index_sequence<I0, Is...> seq ) {
  return two_things{ std::index_sequence<I0>{}, std::index_sequence<Is...>{} };
}

template<std::size_t N, class Seq>
constexpr auto split_sequence( index_t<N>, Seq seq ) {
  constexpr auto step1 = split_sequence( constexpr_index<N/2>, seq );
  constexpr auto step2 = split_sequence( constexpr_index<N-N/2>, step1.b );
  return two_things{ concatenate(step1.a, step2.a), step2.b };
}


template<std::size_t...Is>
constexpr auto halve_sequence( std::index_sequence<Is...> seq ) {
  return split( index< (sizeof...(Is)) / 2u >, seq );
}
```

(`two_things` exists as a many-many-many times lighter tuple or pair than the std one).

That in turn lets you improve filter sequence.

```
template<std::size_t I, class Test>
constexpr auto filter_sequence( std::index_sequence<I> seq, Test test )
{
  if constexpr ( test(constexpr_index<I>) ) {
    return seq;
  } else {
    return std::index_sequence<>{};
  }
}

template<std::size_t...Is, class Test>
constexpr auto filter_sequence( std::index_sequence<Is...> seq, Test test )
{
  constexpr auto split = halve_sequence( seq );
  constexpr auto head = filter_sequence( split.a, test );
  constexpr auto tail = filter_sequence( split.b, test );
  return concatenate(head, tail);
}
```

this version should compile faster and use less memory, especially for large numbers of elements.  But you should start with the simpler one above, because (as I noted) there are probably plenty of tpyos.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/YTMnsb).

Comment: Thanks! Am trying to verify that this works but there seem to be a compile error on the test function. I.e. `error: constexpr if condition is not a constant expression   if constexpr (test(index<I0>))`, which seems a bit weird. Any ideas what that could be about?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman maybe you don't have "lambdas are constexpr by default" feature.  Is that 20 or 17?

Comment: Probably not. I'm using c++17. Seems like I couldn't pass in the test as a r-value reference (or l-value reference), but it worked without any references. So now everything works as expected! https://godbolt.org/z/q7oT35

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I fixed up the divide-and-conquer recursion version as well (link above)

Comment: *"there are probably plenty of **tpyos**."* ^_^

Comment: How about `std::tuple_cat(std::conditional_t<test(index<Is>), std::tuple<index_t<Is>>, std::tuple<>>{}...)`. No recursion (rely on `std::tuple_cat` implementation which might probably do something similar to your code).

Comment: @Jarod42 Not bad.  However, tuple tends to be really really heavy; if there are a lot of indexes, instantiating that many `std::tuple`s will hurt.  Still, we can write `index_cat( std::conditional_t<test(index<Is>)>, std::index_sequence<Is>, std::index_sequence<> >{}... )` really easily.  Ah, but tuple cat in effect requires recursion, as you noted, and our implementation will as well (either depth-N or fancy like the above)